# Angular 5 Observable, return when complete

Tags: angular, observable

Help with Angular 5 Observables.

I want to hide the complexity from the controller; that is to not make it have to subscribe to the observable. Have all the complexity in the service and have it simply return the results/payload to the component. But obviously I'm getting stuck in a timing issue. I feel as if this should be a popular thing/topic, but haven't found the answer. So perhaps I'm going about things wrong?

```
//in the component.ts
const allColors = this.auth.getColors(); //service call
console.log(allColors); // returns undefined

//in the service.ts
getColors() {
  var myColors = "";

  var colors = this.http.get<any>('http://localhost/Account/GetColors', httpOptions)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));

  //
  colors.subscribe(
    res => {
      myColors = res.body;
    },
    error => {}
  );

  return myColors;
}
```

Comment: You cannot simplify up to that point. The service should return the observable itself. You would subscribe to it where you need the result, and use the returned value inside of the subscribe callback.

Comment: I think it's better to embrace Observables rather than work around them because they're integral to how Angular works (among other reasons). It seems like you're trying to make this behave synchronously when it's actually an asynchronous process.

Comment: What you want do would essentially block the execution of the entire application every time you make a http request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I could put the subscribe in the component yes, but doesn't it seem logically that you may want to hide such complexities?

Comment: It is not a complexity but rather a very normal construct that you are interacting with. The more experience you have with observables/promises the more you will see that and realize that you do not actually want to "abstract" these details.

Comment: But if you do want to give a cleaner look to your code see my answer below about using `async` and `await`.

Comment: Ok, so I'll add the subscribe to the component. It just seemed that if you worked with a team of people. Some may setup all the services for others on the team to call and get what they need (without them having to worry about complexes)? But I get there is a point where you can abstract out too far.

Comment: Please note that you can still hide some of the complexity, so that the user of the service does not have to deal with the `http` call and with `res.body` (with the help of the `map` operator).

Answer (score 4):

I think you can't do what you wanna do, because until the subscribe in your service doesn't get resolved it won't send anything to the component, in the execution of the component it's undefined cuz the response haven't come yet.

That's why callback functions are invented. The correct way to do it is having the subscribe in your component cuz you want to wait for the response of the service.

Sorry but I cannot use comments yet so I had to make this reply. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

> So perhaps I'm going about things wrong?

Indeed. Embrace asynchronous programming with Observables and Promises. I believe that is the only reason you are asking this question, you do not fully understand how they work so you want to abstract it away which is something you can't do. See also [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

---

That said you could use [async/await](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-7.html) which can give the *appearance* of synchronous code.

**component.ts**

```
async ngOnInit() {
  const allColors = await this.auth.getColorsAsync(); //service call
  console.log(allColors); // returns color array
}
```

**service.ts**

```
getColorsAsync(): Promise<color[]> {
  return this.http.get<color[]>('http://localhost/Account/GetColors', httpOptions)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
    .toPromise();
}
```

*I guessed as to the actual type. Ideally you should use a strong type over any when possible*

Answer (score 1):

When will your method return? That's the question you need to answer, and to spare you the suspense it will return *prior* to myColors being filled with anything, and that's the nature of asynchronous programming.

You need to return the observable and let it *notify* you when the results are available. This complexity cannot be hidden in the way you are trying, the closest you can get is to pass a callback function into your service method that will then be called with the results when they are available, something like this:

```
getColors(callback) {
    //...

    colors.subscribe(
       res => {
           callback(res.body);
       }
       //...
    );
}
```

But then you'll miss out on a lot of cool functionality, such as being able to have [multiple subscribers](https://coryrylan.com/blog/subscribing-to-multiple-observables-in-angular-components) to the same observable.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a `Resolver` and routing to *pre-load* the data before the service is used.

A resolver is an asynchronized action that is finished before the rest of the routes are activated. So you would define a *top-level* route that doesn't do anything, but contains the resolver to fetch the color data. I say *top-level* because I assume this is global application data. If this data is specific to a feature then place the resolver in the correct routing path.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { 
       path: '',
       resolve: {
           Colors: ColorsResolver
       },
       children: [
             // your application routes here
       ]
    }
]
```

The class `ColorsResolver` would fetch the color data from the server, and then assign it to the service.

```
@Injectable()
export class ColorsResolver implements Resolve<any> {
     public constructor(private colorService: ColorService) {}

     public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
          return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost/Account/GetColors', httpOptions)
                  .do((resp)=> this.colorService.setColor(resp));;
     }
}
```

In your service you just assign the value to a property

```
 @Injectable()
 public ColorService {
     public setColor(resp: any) { this._color = resp; }
     public getColor():any { return this._color; }
 }
```

You can now call `getColor()` many times after the resolver has finished without it blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of what Osakr said. You will have to subscribe in your component.

In your service.ts

```
getColors(): Observable<any> {

    let urlString = 'http://localhost/Account/GetColors'

    return this.http.get(urlString);
  }
```

In your component:

```
getColors() {

    this.service.getColors()
      .subscribe((colors) => {

      this.myColors = colors;

  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in a different way

```
//in the component.ts
this.service.getColors(); //service call
console.log(this.service.allColors); // print the service property.  which will resolve after the oberservable resolve

//in the service.ts
@injectable()
export class Service {
  public allColors: any; //Public property to print.
  public getColors() {
    var myColors = "";

    var colors = this.http.get<any>('http://localhost/Account/GetColors', httpOptions)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));

    colors.subscribe(
      res => {
         this.allColors= res.body;
      },
      error => {}
     );

    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
this.http.get<any>('http://localhost/Account/GetColors', httpOptions)
  .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res.body);
  });
```